# Laravel 5.2 Rednudant (Multiple) Queue Workers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, queue

I have multiple queue workers on my Laravel 5.2 project. I am running on AWS. I am using ECS. I am using Redis for my queue driver.

I would like to know..

If I have 2 servers working the same queue

`php /var/www/laravel/artisan queue:listen --env=production --timeout=30 --tries=1 --queue=mail`

Will they both process the job, thus it gets processed twice? Or will it only get processed once and this will help with the load/redundancy?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A job only exists on a queue once, as soon as a worker grabs the job, it is removed from the queue.

So as long as the different workers are accessing the same instance of the same queue, the jobs will only be executed once.

Comment: Yeh same redis server, I assume it would impossible for them to 'both' grab it as the redis server will deal with requests sequentially?

Comment: And that it also select data from redis as the same time as removing? I guess I mean is it safe or do I need to add any additional configuration before just switching that on.

Comment: Queues are built to only allow one worker access to one job, so it would be safe to do this with the default configuration.

Comment: Excellent, I assume they would only take the job if not busy so it's a good way to share the load also ( mine have a lot of overlaps at times)